# XSD for XML containing XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have created XML Schema for an XML document that describes functionality of components of a complex modular system. Within that XML document, I want to include XML Schema which will be read and parsed to allow for configuration.

`meta-schema.xsd` (heavily edited for brevity):

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:project"
           xmlns="urn:project"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="Schema" type="SchemaType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="SchemaType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="ConfigurationType" name="Configuration"/>
      <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ConfigurationType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="xs:schema"/> <!-- Does not work -->
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The desired XML (written by folks developing modules):

```
<Schema xmlns="urn:project"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:project meta-schema.xsd">
    <!-- Snip -->
    <Configuration>
        <schema>
            <element name="enable" type="boolean">
                <annotation>
                    <appinfo>Usage:</appinfo>
                    <documentation xml:lang="en">
                        Enable functionality
                    </documentation>
                </annotation>
            </element>
        </schema>
    </Configuration>
</Schema>
```

Is this possible to express in XSD? If so, how?

**Edit:**

Based on [kjhughes's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55198425/161366), this is not possible. My solution was to use an `any` element with an `##other` namespace, with a comment:

```
<xs:complexType name="ConfigurationType">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="hex" type="xs:hexBinary"/>
    <xs:element name="base64" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
    <!-- If configuration isn't binary, modules should create an XML Schema of the configuration options in order to
      facilitate future tooling, when feasible. -->
    <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
  </xs:choice>
  <xs:anyAttribute/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Which enables the following XML:

```
 <Schema xmlns="urn:project"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:project meta-schema.xsd">
   <!-- Snip -->
   <Configuration>
      <xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:project"
                 xmlns="urn:project"
                 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 elementFormDefault="qualified">
         <xs:element name="enable" type="xs:boolean">
           <xs:annotation>
             <xs:appinfo>Usage:</xs:appinfo>
             <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
               Enable left radial pulse functionality
             </xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
         </xs:element>
      </xs:schema>
  </Configuration>
</Schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link between an XML document instance and its associated XSD is established via `xsi:schemaLocation` or `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`.

- See [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)

It would be highly unconventional to attempt to physically include the XSD within the XSD.  (There is no XSD equivalent to XML DTD's internal subset.)

- See [Is it possible to use XML Schemas internally, just like DTDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39336531/290085)

You can, of course, always add an attribute or element of type `xs:anyURI` to express such a connection, but that association will be opaque to XML/XSD semantics. You could also use [external entities](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-external-ent) to incorporate any file, including an XSD, but, again, this is a file-level, not an XML/XSD-level mechanism.

Comment: While clearly not the answer I was hoping for, thanks for your clear explanation of why it's not possible.